# Working with Conservative Jews

Tags: employment, heterodox

I am working this summer on a Conservative summer program as a staff member. I discussed with the employer issues of me being orthodox (such as egalitarian davening) and we worked out some  of these problems. The kashrut is reliable (Orthodox certified) and the program is shomer shabbat (although I don't know how legitimate that is). One big concern that I don't know how to deal with is, am I allowed to daven with their minyan if their are women leading? Of course I can daven off to the side, but should I respond amen to their brachot? Are there any other issues that I should be concerned with? How should I deal with them?

Comment: Kashrut? Shabbat?

Comment: As @DoubleAA implies in his comment and Gershon Gold in [his answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15945), there are numerous issues you may have to deal with. Did you mean to ask a more specific question, perhaps?

Comment: ...especially inasmuch as you don't specify any details about the camp. Does it have food you can trust the _kashrus_ of? That might be an issue. Do they go for long walks on _Shabasos_? [That might be an issue.](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15931) In fact, I'm going to close the question as overly broad/ambiguous. I welcome your editing it, though, to remove the ambiguity, and will be glad to reopen it thereafter if you comment here with `@msh210` so I'm alerted.

Comment: In fact, come to think of it, the question as asked is largely a duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8348.

Comment: @msh210 - does this edit make the question any better?

Comment: @Sean, it is as broad as it was, except that you've added an example. If you'd ask only about the example (prayer led by women), that would make a good question IMO. Alternatively, if you ask generally about concerns you have, but removing the ambiguity by specifying what issues will come up in this camp (see my comment of 17:22:42), would also make a good question IMO. As it is, you've left the breadth/ambiguity in.

Comment: real conservative jews, or jews who happen to participate in conservative judaism?

Comment: @Sean, also, in reformulating the question, please keep in mind that [this site does not offer](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/312/perhaps-the-community-moderators-should-enact-a-more-strict-policy-regarding-hal/314#314) personal practical advice.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll ask another question focusing on the davening aspect, which is really my main concern

Answer (score 2):

Is the food Kosher? Is the atmosphere appropriate? Will the woman be dressed modestly?

Comment: The food is kosher. The women are allowed to wear shorts and t shirts. What kind of atmosphered do you mean?